# SFTP connection failed (Password Less Server)

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, sshd

I have configured a password less SFTP server.
I want to connect it using jsch (JAVA) library with username and password.
I have been using following line of code :-

> session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", 
>              "password,hostbased,publickey");

Will this line in JAVA override the settings of SSH configuration (Password Less)?

Please note SFTP server is connecting well using terminal command SFTP, without prompting password.

Comment: What is "Password Less Server"? What doy ou mean by that? + Show us a JSch log file, as well as `ssh -v ...` output (both running on the same machine, connecting to the same server).

Answer (score 0):

No. It will not override the server SSH configuration.

This line of code will only tell the ssh client (i.e. your code) what type of authentication methods to try when attempting to connect to the SFTP server.

The client will try the first method that is also supported by the server and attempt to create the connection using this method.

This is explained well in [this JSch javadoc](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html)

Of course, you will have to configure your SSH server to allow password authentication. To do that, you should open the ssh_config file under:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

And uncomment the following line

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jsch library you can achieve this as mentioned below.

Initialize Jsch and get a `com.jcraft.jsch.Session` object from it, then set `UserInfo` in this `Session` object

Non connect the session with a time out value and then open a channel to transfer the file.

```
    if(null != session && !session.isConnected()){
            session.connect(10000); 
    }

   ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) 
   session.openChannel(UIConstants.SFTP);
   sftpChannel.connect();
```

You need ChannelSftp for file transfer.

More detail at Jsch library [https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html](http://Jsch%20library)

Comment: How does this answer the question?